# Firefox errors when running from terminal

Tags: linux, linux-mint, firefox

When I run Firefox from the terminal in, I receive many errors.  I suspect that they have to do with my plug-ins.

My terminal output:

```
user@Basically-a-Toaster ~ $ firefox

(process:3628): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:3628): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:3628): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:3628): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:3628): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised console.error:  Could not read session file    Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js (Permission denied)    console.error:    Could not read session file   Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.bak (Permission denied)    console.error:    Could not read session file   Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/previous.js (Permission denied)    console.error:    Could not read session file   Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/upgrade.js-20150826185918 (Permission denied)    console.error: random-agent-spoofer:    Message: Module `sdk/widget` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js   Stack:
    CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 @resource://jid1-avgcef1zovzmja-at-jetpack/random-agent-spoofer/lib/Widget.js:1:14 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 @resource://jid1-avgcef1zovzmja-at-jetpack/random-agent-spoofer/lib/Ras.js:1:14 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 @resource://jid1-avgcef1zovzmja-at-jetpack/random-agent-spoofer/lib/Panel.js:3:11 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 @resource://jid1-avgcef1zovzmja-at-jetpack/random-agent-spoofer/lib/main.js:1:1 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:145:19 startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7 Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:922:23 this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:801:7 this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:740:39

console.error: random-agent-spoofer:    Message: Module `sdk/widget` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js   Stack:
    CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 @resource://jid1-avgcef1zovzmja-at-jetpack/random-agent-spoofer/lib/Widget.js:1:14 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 @resource://jid1-avgcef1zovzmja-at-jetpack/random-agent-spoofer/lib/Ras.js:1:14 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 @resource://jid1-avgcef1zovzmja-at-jetpack/random-agent-spoofer/lib/Panel.js:3:11 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 @resource://jid1-avgcef1zovzmja-at-jetpack/random-agent-spoofer/lib/main.js:1:1 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18 run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:145:19 startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7 Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:922:23 this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:801:7 this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:740:39

console.error:    Could not write session state file    Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js.tmp (Permission denied)    console.error:    Could not write session state file    Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js.tmp (Permission denied)    console.error: privacybadger:    Policy document request to https://ajax.googleapis.com/.well-known/dnt-policy.txt returned with status 404 console.error:    Could not write session state file    Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js.tmp (Permission denied)    console.error:    Could not write session state file    Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js.tmp (Permission denied)    console.error:    Could not write session state file    Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js.tmp (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

The GTK warning are not important. As for the errors , this one

```
Message: Unix error 13 during operation open on file /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js.tmp (Permission denied)
```

is explicit. It tells you do not have permission acces. Please show output of this command:

```
$ls -al home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore- backups/recovery.js.tmp
```

It will tell you permissions on the file.

Comment: `ls: cannot access home/user/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-: No such file or directory`  
`ls: cannot access backups/recovery.js.tmp: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Paradox The space in their command is unintentional. There should be no space after the dash in `sessionstore-backups`.